# How to provide a readonly Collection that implements INotifyCollectionChanged

Tags: c#, vb.net

Is there a efficient way to provide an `Enumarable<SomeType>` or a collection that implements INotifyCollectionChanged but that can only be changed from the inside of the providing class.

The following example shows what I mean, but has the disadvantage that the caller can cast the `IEnumerable<SomeType>` back and then manipulate my internal collection, what I really would dislike:

```
public class DemoClass{

    ObservableCollection<SomeType> m_collection=
                                   new ObservableCollection<SomeType>();

    public IEnumerable<SomeType> SomeTypeInstances{
         get{return m_collection;}
    }

    private void AMethod(){
        // Here I can work with m_collection            
    }

}
```

Is there an easy way, perhaps with the ObservableCollection, or is it necessary to write a wrapper that implements `IEnumerable<SomeType>` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` and then forwarding collectionchanged-evnets to the destination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620.aspx).

Comment: Perfect! Excactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you return the internal collection then they can always mess with your data. you could just give the user a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` that is a clone of the internal data. That way, they can get to the data and your data isn't at risk of being corrupted.